# how to select random points evenly distributed along the point cloud for iterative closest point method in python

Tags: python, transformation, point-clouds

I am trying to code the ICP methodology in python and I need to select my initial points to do the transformations. However, those random points have to be evenly distributed. How can select random points evenly distributed along the point cloud to preform icp? I was thinking of splitting the point cloud into grids, however I am not sure how to implement that or if that will work

Comment: Maybe you could work something out using [random.uniform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)

Comment: how would that work?

Comment: How are your points stored? If they are in an octree, then they're effectively already in a grid.

Comment: A simple method would be to select the random points one by one, using weights, giving a high weights to points that are far from already-selected points, and a low weight to points that are close to already-selected points.